# AngularJS Material Slide Left to Right CSS3 Animation

Tags: angularjs, css, angular-material, css-animations

I am trying to "translate" this [AngularJS slide left / right example](http://embed.plnkr.co/WNdrmy2VWFicj0vocGcp/preview) to [an AngularJS Material one.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MzexVd?editors=0000)

The latter link consists of the following code snippets:

#### HTML code:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController" ng-app="switchExample">
  <!--<select ng-model="slide" ng-options="item as item.name for item in slides">
  </select>-->
  <code>slide={{slide}}</code>
  <code>moveToLeft={{mtl}}</code>
  <md-button ng-click="prev()"><</md-button>
  <md-button ng-click="next()">></md-button>
  <div class="">
      <div class="ngSwitchItem" ng-if="slide.name == 'first'" ng-class="{'moveToLeft' : mtl}">
        <div class="firstPage page" md-swipe-left="selectPage(1)">
          first
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ngSwitchItem" ng-if="slide.name == 'second'" ng-class="{'moveToLeft' : mtl}">
        <div class="secondPage page" md-swipe-right="selectPage(0)" md-swipe-left="selectPage(2)">
        second
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ngSwitchItem" ng-if="slide.name == 'third'" ng-class="{'moveToLeft' : mtl}">
        <div class="thirdPage page" md-swipe-right="selectPage(1)" md-swipe-left="selectPage(3)">
        third
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ngSwitchItem" ng-if="slide.name == 'fourth'" ng-class="{'moveToLeft' : mtl}">
        <div class="fourthPage page" md-swipe-right="selectPage(2)">
        fourth
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JS code

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('switchExample', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.slides = [
      { index: 0, name: 'first' }, 
      { index: 1, name: 'second' }, 
      { index: 2, name: 'third' }, 
      { index: 3, name: 'fourth' }
    ];
    $scope.selectPage = selectPage;
    /**
    * Initialize with the first page opened
    */
    $scope.slide = $scope.slides[0];

    $scope.prev = () => {
      if ($scope.slide.index > 0) {
        selectPage($scope.slide.index - 1);
      }
    }

    $scope.next = () => {
      if ($scope.slide.index < 3) {
        selectPage($scope.slide.index + 1);
      }
    }

    /**
    * @name selectPage
    * @desc The function that includes the page of the indexSelected
    * @param indexSelected the index of the page to be included
    */
    function selectPage(indexSelected) {
        if ($scope.slides[indexSelected].index > $scope.slide.index) {
            $scope.mtl = false;
        } else {
            $scope.mtl = true;
        }
        $scope.slide = $scope.slides[indexSelected];
    }
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```

#### CSS code

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.ngSwitchItem {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    animation-duration: 10.30s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 10.30s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;

}

.page {
    position: inherit;
    top: 0;
    right: inherit;
    bottom: inherit;
    left: inherit;
}

.firstPage {
    background-color: blue;
}

.secondPage {
    background-color: red;
}

.thirdPage {
    background-color: green;
}

.fourthPage {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* When the page enters, slide it from the right */
.ngSwitchItem.ng-enter {
    animation-name: slideFromRight;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromRight;
}
/* When the page enters and moveToLeft is true, slide it from the left(out of the user view) to the right (left corner) */
.ngSwitchItem.moveToLeft.ng-enter {
    animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromLeft;
}
/* When the page leaves, slide it to left(out of the user view) from the left corner,
    in other words slide it from the left(out of the view) to the left corner but in reverse order */
.ngSwitchItem.ng-leave {
    animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromLeft;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
}
/* When the page leaves, slide it to the right(out of the user view) from the the left corner,
    in other words, slide it from the right but in reverse order  */
.ngSwitchItem.moveToLeft.ng-leave {
    animation-name: slideFromRight;
    animation-direction: reverse;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideFromRight;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
}

@keyframes slideFromRight {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@keyframes slideFromLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideFromRight {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideFromLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    }

    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

As seen, however, the second one doesn't behave as the first one, WHEN slide direction has changed. 
For instance:

1. I slide to left the first one --> second slide loads with the correct animation
2. Then, I slide to right the second one --> it is supposed the first slide to start appearance from the left side, while the second one to start disappearance to to the right side. Instead, as you may see, the second one start to disappear to the left and from the right side a white slide is shown. At some point, the first slide starts its appearance from the middle of the content.

Please note, I deliberately delay the animations on the second example, just to see the undesired side effect mode clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after a few more research hours, I found where the problem was buried - it seems, I have to move scope variable change for the next tick, to give time `ng-class` change to make its "magic".

Long story short - adding the following is what made the thing work:

```
$timeout(() => {
  $scope.slide = $scope.slides[indexSelected];
}, 0)
```

Here is [the updated example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RqGpBe) and the code snippet below:

#### JS code

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('switchExample', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.slides = [
      { index: 0, name: 'first' }, 
      { index: 1, name: 'second' }, 
      { index: 2, name: 'third' }, 
      { index: 3, name: 'fourth' }
    ];
    $scope.selectPage = selectPage;
    /**
    * Initialize with the first page opened
    */
    $scope.slide = $scope.slides[0];

    $scope.prev = () => {
      if ($scope.slide.index > 0) {
        selectPage($scope.slide.index - 1);
      }
    }

    $scope.next = () => {
      if ($scope.slide.index < 3) {
        selectPage($scope.slide.index + 1);
      }
    }

    /**
    * @name selectPage
    * @desc The function that includes the page of the indexSelected
    * @param indexSelected the index of the page to be included
    */
    function selectPage(indexSelected) {
        if ($scope.slides[indexSelected].index > $scope.slide.index) {
            $scope.mtl = false;
        } else {
            $scope.mtl = true;
        }
      // this will move a scope variable change to the next tick, 
      // hence will give time $scope.mtl to be handled by ng-class
      $timeout(() => {
        $scope.slide = $scope.slides[indexSelected];
      }, 0)

    }
  }]);
})(window.angular);
```